# Script to Update Host File

Tags: scripts

I have the following command that correctly creates the /etc/hosts file that I want to build.  However, I cannot write it per the 2nd form due to permissions, of course.  So I tried variations of the 3rd form, but it still errors on permissions.  Can someone give me a suggestion to try?

```
cat hosts.tmp ; echo -n "myremotehost " ; cat ip.txt

cat hosts.tmp ; echo -n "myremotehost " ; cat ip.txt > /etc/hosts

cat hosts.tmp ; echo -n "myremotehost " ; echo mypassword | sudo -S cat ip.txt > /etc/hosts
```

Comment: I suspect you might be trying to re-invent the wheel here: http://gaenserich.github.io/hostsblock -- anyway, if that's not the case, you can perhaps get answers to your question(s) in the script(s) there ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This was hard for me to find out! (Relative newbie to Linux.)

In terminal, type `sudo -i`, then log in with your user password.
You will be in the root directory, with God-like powers...  :>)

I also found `bash filename.sh` will start the script.
Forgive me, I feel a great sense of accomplishment having 
written a script (per suggestions in another post) which
killed all ads in Youtube!

Answer (score -1):

I would put the instructions to modify your `/etc/hosts` file in a shell script, say `modify-hosts.sh`, then execute

```
sudo modify-hosts.sh
```

If you insist on running the script without having to provide a password, then add a `NOPASSWD` entry specifically for this script and your username to `/etc/sudoers`.

As for the contents of the file, you could do:

```
cp hosts.tmp > /etc/hosts
echo "myremotehost $(cat /path/to/ip.txt)" >> /etc/hosts
```

More conveniently, if `myhostname` already has an entry in `/etc/hosts` you can edit it in place:

```
sed -i -e 's/myhostname .*/myhostname '$(cat ip.txt)'/' /etc/hosts
```

And that statement you can even `sudo` on one line

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/myhostname .*/myhostname '$(cat ip.txt)'/' /etc/hosts
```

without running into redirection issues.